# Twilio startConferenceOnEnter set to true, but still ending up in the waitUrl

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I've just made this TwiML test file.  I've set the Voice URL in my account to point to this file but when i'm calling my number, i hear the message but the user end up in a waiting room even if i've set the startConferenceOnEnter to true.  Anyone can explain me what i'm doing wrong?   I was expecting the user to end up in a room with no sound at all.

Thanks you

```
@{
    Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
}
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Say voice="woman" language="FR">Bienvenue sur le pont de conférence Twilio.</Say>      

    <Dial>
        <Conference startConferenceOnEnter="true" endConferenceOnExit="false" record="do-not-record">
        1234567
        </Conference>
    </Dial> 
</Response>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

[`startConferenceOnEnter`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/conference#attributes-startConferenceOnEnter) will still wait for more than one person to be on the conference before starting.

If you are looking to stop their being wait music while the caller waits for someone else to join, you can set the [`waitUrl`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/conference#attributes-waitUrl) to an empty string `""`, like so:

```
@{
    Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
}
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Say voice="woman" language="FR">Bienvenue sur le pont de conférence Twilio.</Say>      

    <Dial>
        <Conference startConferenceOnEnter="true" endConferenceOnExit="false" record="do-not-record" waitUrl="">
        1234567
        </Conference>
    </Dial> 
</Response>
```

Let me know if that helps at all.